# Java - Multiple "for" operators in loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, 3d, logic

How does this code work? 
(It generates a cuboid made of blocks, using given size (x,y,z) and coordinates (coordX, coordY, coordZ))

```
...
public void cuboid(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < y; k++)
                for(int l = 0; l < z; l++)
            {
             Grass.setBlock(j + coordX, k + coordY, l + coordZ);
            }
...
```

How do work multiple "for" operators? I think, there is a way to do it much more effectively.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be trivially answered by adding print statements, using a debugger or just writing it out on a piece of paper. Stack Overflow is not a substitution for a class, a book, a tutorial or common sense.

Comment: Uh, i did not think about it.

Comment: I don't really agree, there is nothing o debug here, the OP is asking for a code explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the following code:

```
int rows = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= rows, i++)
{
     for (int j = 1; j <= i)
          System.out.print("*");
     System.out.println("");
}
```

If you run it, you'll get a pyramid where each row of stars has the same number of stars as the row number. Try tracing through it.

What you'll find is that with multiple fors, the innermost loop runs until its variable is the value of its parent loop, which will run until its variable is the value of its parent loop (...)

Basically, it runs a lot.
When i == 1, the j loop runs once. When i == 2, the j loop runs twice. 
If there were three (say, i,j,k), k would run j times, which would run i times. I would increment, which would travel into j(starts all over), which would travel into k(starts all over). I know this isn't super clear, but it is difficult to explain. It requires a kind of intuitive leap.

As far as simplicity/effectiveness, I'm not sure but IMHO this is a fine way to do it.

Comment: Yes but the same feature applies if its a cube. You're starting at a corner and fillings width, adding a row, filling width, etc. till length is filled. Then move up a layer and start over, until height is filled

Comment: Yep, but some elements of your explanation don't apply to the cube, well at least you try I'll admit it is difficult to answer

Comment: Its kind of esoteric. Like i said you have to make that intuitive leap. Or be willing to step through the loops and understand it.

Comment: Thank you, you made this clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you think it is not efficient. If the goal is to build a large cuboid of size `x,y,z` from unitary cubes, then you will need `x*y*z` unitary cubes... as this code performs **exactly** `x*y*z` calls, it cannot be more efficient as this.